# Why is there a one-to-one correspondence between homomorphic images of a group $G$ and normal subgroups of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

I was reading about group theory in Herstein's book (mentioned below) and I came across a couple of propositions that were not clear to me, in the sense that I couldn't quite figure out why they were true and I would really appreciate if you could help me understand them.

They are the following:

> Thus there is a one-to-one correspondence between homomorphic images
>   of G and normal subgroups of G. [...]
>   The set of groups so constructed yields all homomorphic images of G
>   (up to isomorphisms).

*Herstein, I. N.*, Topics in algebra, Lexington, TX: Xerox College Publishing. xi, 388 p. (1975). [ZBL1230.00004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1230.00004).

*The constructed set mentioned in the quote above is the set $ \left\{G/N: N \triangleleft G \right\} $*

I can understand why given a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, one can associate a homomorphic image of G, namely, $G/N$, but is the converse true, I mean, can I associate a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ given a homomorphic image of a group $G$? How exactly does the given set yield **all** homomorphic images of $G$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a direct consequence of the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: To be more precise, there is a one-to-one correspondence between **isomorphism types** of homomorphic images of $G$ and normal subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick between the correspondence lies in the isomorphism theorems. You already know that to every normal subgroup of $G$ there corresponds a unique homomorphic image (upto isomorphism). Now, suppose that $h:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $\ker(h)$ is normal, and by the first isomorphism theorem
$$G/\ker(h)\cong h(G).$$

Comment: I'm sorry if that's too basic of a question, but what exactly do you mean by "up to isomorphism"?

Comment: @Lucas Cruz Upto basically means that, excluding some property. In this context it means that we are considering groups the same if they are isomorphic. 

For example, 
$$G/G\cong\left<\{0\},+\right>,$$
and
$$G/G\cong\left<\{1\},\cdot\right>.$$
Technically the groups on the right are not the same, however, they are isomorphic. Which is why in the correspondence we consider two groups the same if they are isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifications, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Lucas Cruz You're welcome, and I'm glad :)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the First Ismorphism Theorem. Let's say $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$, i.e. there exists a morphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi : G \to H$ is surjective. Then $N:= \text{ker} \ \varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/N \cong H$. Then the correspondence
\begin{align}
\{ \text{normal subgroups of } G \} &\to \{ \text{homomorphic image of } G \} \\
N &\mapsto G/N
\end{align}
is inverse to (up to isomorphism)
\begin{align}
\{ \text{homomorphic image of } G \} &\to \{ \text{normal subgroups of } G \} \\
H &\mapsto N:= \text{ker} \ \varphi, \text{ where } \varphi : G \to H.
\end{align}